# Завершить выполнение PHP скрипта

Tags: php

На странице `cabinet.html` висит скрипт проверки новых пользовательских данных. Работает следующим образом:

1. AJAX отправляет "длинный" запрос на скрипт `test.php`
2. В скрипте `test.php`работает цикл, который каждые 2 секунды проверяет наличие новых данных в таблице БД.
3. При появлении новых данных, скрипт `test.php` обрывает цикл и отправляет данные клиенту.
4. Клиент приняв данные и вставив их на страницу, снова отправляет "длинный" запрос и снова ждёт появления новых данных в БД.
5. Если в пункте 4, в качестве ответа от сервера клиент принял timeout, то в этом случае он также отправляет новый "длинный" запрос на сервер.

Цикл в скрипте `test.php` работает 20 секунд (поставил ограничение). При истечении 20-ти секунд, скрипт отправляет `timeout` клиенту. Кажется всё это люди называют `long poll`. Данные методы мне вполне понятны, но возникла проблема следующего характера. Если мы покинем страницу `cabinet.html`, скрипт `test.php` всё ещё продолжает работать (до истечения тех 20 секунд). Как завершить работу этого скрипта, в случае если мы ушли со страницы?

Файл test.php:

```
$limit = 20; // лимит работы нашего цикла 20 секунд
$t = time();

while(true) {
    if(time() < $t+$limit) {
        //проверяем данные
        if(2+2 == 5) { // это для демонстрации
            // отправляем ответ клиенту
            break;
            exit;
        } else {
            sleep(2);
        }
    } else {
        // отправляем timeout
        break;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: ignore_user_abort(false) и connection_aborted() - кажется не решают проблему. Надо поковыряться.

Comment: Не по теме, но использовать вебсокеты вместо long poll не пробовали?

Comment: Эндрю, такой вариант рассматривался очень давно, но если мне не изменяет память, кажется данный вариант отпал, из-за каких-то ограничений. Кажется на количество подключений.

Comment: В вебсокетах в целом ограничений на количество подключений нет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> Если мы покинем страницу cabinet.html, скрипт test.php всё ещё продолжает работать(по истечении тех 20 секунд)

Да, потому что клиент отправил запрос, сервер обязан его обработать, а статуса подключения, чтобы его проверять, на уровне HTTP не существует. Я не очень понимаю как должен работать `ignore_user_abort`, разве что на уровне tcp-подключения, и, судя по всему, он и [не работает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5997140/2908793).

Самым лучшим решением было бы просто отказаться от long polling и оббивать сервер аякс-запросами раз в две секунды. Ну, в идеале вообще websocket, но это потребует много ресурсов.

Comment: Когда AJAX отсоединяется от скрипта test.php (переходом на другую страницу) не будет ли это считаться "отключением клиента"?

Comment: @stashappy у него нет понятия "отсоединяется" вообще в принципе. У запроса нет состояния "отменен", он либо ушел с указанием обратного адресата (это уже не на уровне http), либо нет.

Comment: Могу ли я вас попросить ознакомиться с этой страницей: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.connection-handling.php и ещё раз прокомментировать работу функции ignore_user_abort()? Я в смятении, для чего-же тогда нужна эта функция?

Comment: Я не знаю, потому что физически отменить HTTP/1.x запрос невозможно.

Comment: @Etki Отменить запрос можно. Попробуйте запросить через медленное соединение у веб сервера большой файл. Он вам начнет его передавать и в этот момент вы разорвете соединение. Как на ваш взгляд поступет веб сервер? Будет продолжать отдавать вам файл?

Comment: @Ruslan, почитайте про сетевой стек и общение в рамках HTTP. Сам HTTP-запрос, повторюсь, отменить невозможно, по крайней мере в первой версии протокола. В случае с файлом рвется более низкоуровневое соединение, и это не отмена пакета, а **превранная на транспортном уровне передача пакета**. Веб-сервер, в принципе, волен пробовать восстановить соединение и продолжать слать пакеты, хотя никто, конечно, так делать не будет.

Comment: Дорогой друг. Отменить запрос не проблема. Для xhr есть например abort(). Но должен ли нас волновать сам запрос? Нас должен волновать не запрос, а php-скрипт, который остался выполняться в фоновом режиме, после того, как мы ушли со страницы.

Comment: @Etki Мне кажется вы что-то путаете. Рекомендую вам ознакомится более внимательно с понятием HTTP протокол. То что вы сделали запрос на сервер - действительно не отменить, но сам процесс обработки вашего запроса отменить легко просто разорвав соединение и восстанавливать его HTTP сервер не будет  да и не сможет.

Comment: @Ruslan, и вот этот самый "разрыв соединения", нам надо как-то и проверить нашим php-скриптом. Должно же быть нечто(на стороне сервера), что проверяло бы наличие соединения с клиентом.

Comment: @stashappy [Connection_aborted](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.connection-aborted.php) разве не подходит?

Comment: @Ruslan, в HTTP нет понятия "подключение". Оно есть на уровне TCP, и, как видно из комментариев к соответствующим функциям, ловить разрыв соединения PHP получается не очень. Кроме того, интерпретатор может оказаться за проксей, за fcgi-клиентом, за каким-нибудь туннелем и еще за миллиардом вещей, которые не будут рвать коннект даже если отвалился пользователь. *То что вы сделали запрос на сервер - действительно не отменить* - это как раз-таки кейс автора вообще-то.

Comment: @Etki Я не вижу смысла спорить. Вы пытаетесь доказать что? Что PHP тяжело отловить разрыв? Его не элементарно отловить даже работая напрямую с TCP протоколом, но при чем здесь это? И кейс автора не отменить запрос, а отловить разрыв. Как будет работать и будет ли вообще? Не знаю, но проверять connection_aborted можно и нужно. Также рекомендую ему отправлять данные клиенту (пусть пустые), но в любом случае т.к. соединение может быть разорвано по таймауту тем же прокси на входе.

Comment: Ребята. Вот здесь есть статья как раз об этом http://smelukov.com/php-halt автор которой пишет: "Дело в том, что php может узнать — прервано соединение или нет, только когда он пытается что-то вывести (то есть отдать контент пользователю).". Кажется в эту сторону и надо копать.

Comment: Пол дня пытаюсь заставить работать функцию  connection_aborted(). Как её вообще использовать, непонятно. Ребята. У кого есть чутка времени, можно вас попросить скинуть пример её использования? Простой примитивный пример, вроде этого: if(connection_aborted()) { echo "УРА!!!"; }

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29493/discussion-on-answer-by-etki---php-).

Answer (score 1):

Прервать выполнение в таком контексте не получится. Но можно попробовать отправлять дополнительный AJAX запрос в случае закрытия странички, аля [onbeforeunload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp)

AJAX запрос будет создавать какой-то темповый файл, а внутри цикла вы будете его уже проверять на существование.